# Dynamically generating columns of dataset,rdlc report in c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, dataset, rdlc

My task is to create an rdlc report which has dynamic columns (whose numbers keeps on changing). I have a datatable which contains number of columns and rows(data). Now I need to create dataset and rdlc report (rdlc wisard) dynamically.

I have tried out with this code but no luck till now. ds3 is a dataset which contains datatable.

```
this.reportViewer1.Reset();
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("Report.rdlc");
ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("ds1", ds3);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
this.reportViewer1.DataBind();
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Comment: In you case, do you have a finite number of options for column sets or do you need to create a report with unpredictable number of columns based on the dataset. In the earlier case, you can maybe play with column visibility to achieve what you need, but in the latter, the best option would be to create a matrix report which can be done by adding Row Groups and Column Groups in the RDLC report. Can you please show an example with some dummy data of what your case is?

Comment: I have unpredictable columns.I have grid,upon selecting (cell content click) on a particular option it displays n number of columns with data in it.my grid has various choices(records) where each selection has different number of columns (ex:if i select america in grid it has say some 100 columns,and if i select newzealand it has say 50 colums) so my work is to display all 100 columns with data upon selecting  america and if selected newzealand it should display 50 columns with data.which is nothing but dynamically generating columns and displaying in rdlc report.

Comment: I think the best option is to treat the columns the same as rows and make it as a matrix. One way is to create a class `ReportCell` which has `Column`, `Row` and `Value` properties. In the RDLC report, you can group columns by the `Column` property of the dataset and rows by the `Row` property of the data set. This would require to change the logic you fetch the dataset because now `ds3` has to be a `IEnumerable<ReportCell>`.

Comment: sorry for the late reply.Thanks for your suggestion.I have to create rdlc report without creating dataset(.xsd) or report viewer which means i cant drag and drop columns of table in dataset. i have datatable,by using this datatable it should automatically create dataset.